# Custom map with C++

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap, hashtable

I want to create a custom map. I don't want to compare the key, I want the second element on map, I don't really know how to explain this so here is some code I have written which will hopefully explain what I want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct box {
    int size, color, price, position;
};

struct custom_compare {
    bool operator()(const box& lhs, const box& rhs) const {
        if(lhs.size  != rhs.size)  return lhs.size < rhs.size;
        if(lhs.color != rhs.color) return lhs.color < rhs.color;
        if(lhs.price != rhs.price) return lhs.price < rhs.price;
        return lhs.position < rhs.position;
    }
};

int main() {                   //here, box isn't the key
    std::map<std::string, box, custom_compare> box_map;
    box_map["my box"] = {1,5,200,1};
    box_map["jose's box"] = {3,1,300,2};
    box_map["maria's box"] = {2,4,100,3};
    // The problem is that the custom_compare get 'box_map.first', not 'box_map.second'
    // I wish map compare struct box, not string
}
```

I can't put the struct on key, I need the associativity.

So, is there a way to custom compare a map based on the second element(not the key)?

Comment: _"I can't put the struct on key, i need the associativity."_ So you mean you need the association to a unique `std::string` for each `box` instance?

Comment: Is it possible that you could get the box using the key and then once you have the box you could compare the second values of the map.

Comment: Yes, exactly, πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: Are you looking for Boost.Bimap or Boost.Multiindex?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why you are trying to sort by value, and not by key?

Comment: i need to insert and increment values to a struct based on a unkown input(need the associativity). And, sort based on some criteria, Nasser

Comment: i think Boost.Bimap should resolve the issue.

Comment: Edit your question to give examples of the sort of lookups and other operations you'd like to do on the map. As is, it's difficult to see what you're trying to make possible.

Comment: I found the question, a better way of saying it would be "map sort by value", i think my question is duplicated